# Javascript Isn't Running in HTML Webpage When Inputting Data

Tags: javascript, html, css, submit

Whenever I run the code it brings me to the webpage and everything appears fine but when I submit a value wihtin the text box, nothing happens. It just restarts the webpage with the submission and thats it. I don't get any of the alerts in the code.

My Code: [CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v5sm.png)

I tried putting the  into the head or the body and still no change. I tried changing values and changing orders but still nothing. I'm pretty certain I'm not spelling anything incorrectly because I did't get any red underlines and I looked over the code a couple times and didn't notice any misspellings. I expect to have one the three alerts to appear whenever a value is submitted on the webpage.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please use the code syntax to post your code instead of providing an image of your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you're still learning the basics, but this is something you should watch tutorials on, and maybe look at other people's code to get a better understanding of how `JavaScript` works.

All you need is the `preventDefault()` function, that can be run on an event, like `submit`. This is really only important in the case of forms. Here's how the `preventDefault()` function works:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form'),
      responseList = document.querySelector('ul')

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

  e.preventDefault()
  
  const inputs = e.target.querySelectorAll('input')
  
  inputs.forEach(input => {
  
    const responseOutput = document.createElement('li'),
          {name, value} = input
    
    responseOutput.innerText = `${name}: ${value}`
    
    responseList.appendChild(responseOutput)
    
  })
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="Anything" />
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="Something Else" />
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<br>

<div>
  <span>Response:</span>
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

I should also mention, that in your case, you should switch to using an `onsubmit` on the `` rather than an `onclick` on the ``. It will make it more clear. That is, if you don't want to use an `addEventListener()` like I use in my example.